# how to prevent model-changes-listener (binded with $watch) invocation inside ngClick function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have model, and I watch this model for some changes with functions binded in $watch. And I have function binded to ngClick, who change model. I need to be able to prevent model listener invocation in ngClick, because I don't want track that changes, but if model changed with some other way, except ngClick binded function, I want listeners work.

But I don't want to unbind listeners, I just want it to stop execution for this current moment.

example:

```
$scope.AlertIfChange = function(){
 alert('model changes!');
};

$scope.watch(model, AlertIfChange, true);

$scope.clickHandler = function(){
 $scope.model = "changed by click";
 -- some stuff to prevent AlertIfChange invocation --
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$scope.AlertIfChange = function(){
    if(!$scope.clickChanged){           
        alert("I was not changed by click");
    }
    else{
        alert("I was changed by click");
    }
};
$watch(model, AlertIfChange, true);

$scope.clickChanged = false;

$scope.clickHandler = function(){
    $scope.model = "changed by click";
    $scope.clickChanged = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. And currently I implement it that way, but I'm curious - is it possible to do that with some native way without flags.

Comment: Nope. I dont think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this functionality in a lot of places, consider writing a directive which works like ng-click, but doesn't trigger the callback until a specific condition is met.